# Multiple Textfield Views in NavigationView not binding input to ViewModel

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have a NavigationView with 4 different views pushed onto the stack via NavigationLinks.

Each view has a TextField whose input is $binded to a property in the ViewModel.

When I enter the text and push a new view onto the stack the input is not binded/saved to the ViewModel. I know this because I try printing out the previously entered text or displaying the previously entered text on the next view.

What am i doing wrong?

Here is my code...

```
class SignupNavigationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
      var email = ""
      var username = ""
      var password = ""
      var reconfirmPassword = ""
}

// first view
struct SignupEmailView: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()

    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("enter your e-mail", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.email )
                }
                NavigationLink("continue", destination: ConfirmCodeView())
                Spacer()
               
            }
        }
     }
  }

// second view
struct ConfirmCodeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()
   
    var body: some View {
        
            VStack {
            TextField("Enter code sent to your email", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode)
            NavigationLink("confirm", destination: SignupUsername() )
            }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
     }  
}

  //etc..
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to pass the same instance of `SignupNavigationViewModel` to your next view. Right now, it's creating a new instance entirely.

```
class SignupNavigationViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var email = ""
    @Published var username = ""
    @Published var password = ""
    @Published var reconfirmPassword = ""
}

// first view
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel = SignupNavigationViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            VStack {
                HStack {
                    TextField("enter your e-mail", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.email )
                }
                NavigationLink("continue", destination: ConfirmCodeView(signupNavigationViewModel: signupNavigationViewModel)) //<-- Here
                Spacer()
                
            }
        }
    }
}

// second view
struct ConfirmCodeView: View {
    @ObservedObject var signupNavigationViewModel : SignupNavigationViewModel //<-- Here
    
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Text("Email: \(signupNavigationViewModel.email)")
            TextField("Enter code sent to your email", text: $signupNavigationViewModel.emailCode)
            NavigationLink("confirm", destination: Text("Destination") )
        }.navigationBarBackButtonHidden(true)
    }
}
```

That way, they're sharing the same data. Note that I also changed your view model properties to `@Published` so that the views will respond to them dynamically if the values change.